# How can I extend existing tmLanguage Colorizer/ Syntax highlighter?

Tags: sublimetext2, syntax-highlighting, visual-studio-code, tmlanguage

I'm trying to extend https://github.com/dzannotti/vscode-babel/blob/master/syntaxes/Babel%20Language.json but all my attempts just result in a complete override, leaving the text blank. I'd rather not be a jerk and just copy the code into my highlighter.

I want to extend the colorizer and just add my patterns ontop of it.

Here's my current attempt:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
       <key>fileTypes</key>
       <array>
          <string>js</string>
       </array>
       <key>name</key>
       <string>Handlebars (Ember.js)</string>
       <key>patterns</key>
       <array>
          <dict>
             <key>actions</key>
             <string>actions</string>
             <key>match</key>
             <string>actions</string>
             <key>name</key>
             <string>keyword</string>
          </dict>
          <dict>
         <key>include</key>
         <string>text.javascript.basic</string>
      </dict>

   </array>
   <key>scopeName</key>
   <string>source.js.jsx</string>
```

I was trying to do what's in this [thread](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/how-to-extend-an-already-existing-tmlanguge/5452) but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You should probably at least look at the Babel JavaScript syntax definition to see what its base scope is. In this case it's `source.js.jsx`, not `text.javascript.basic`. Programming languages generally use the `source` scope, while text and markup languages (Markdown, HTML, XML, etc.) use `text`. If you're going to be developing syntax definitions, I highly recommend using the [**`ScopeAlways`**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ScopeAlways) and/or [**`ScopeHunter`**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ScopeHunter) plugins for determining the scopes active at the current cursor location.